# Index and orientdb

Tags: indexing, orientdb

I created an index in orientdb with all edges of a graph. to make the query:

```
select from index: Where unique_edge key = # 9: 1
```

as a result in the web console I get

```
OCompositeKey {keys = [# 9: 1, # 9: 0]}
OCompositeKey {keys = [# 9: 1, # 12: 0]}
```

and the same query in java console have

```
# 3: -1
# 3: -1
```

I need to get the vertices of the edges that is

```
# 9: 1, # 9: 0, # 12: 0.
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi, can you post your schema? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
select both() from #9:1
```

becuase your index will not improve the speed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, and How I get the two vertices but separately i.e. in two queries

Comment: select in() from #9:1 and select out() from #9:1

Answer (score -1):

To create de index

```
OCommandSQL declareIn= new OCommandSQL();
declareIn.setText("CREATE PROPERTY E.in LINK");
OCommandSQL declareOut= new OCommandSQL();
declareOut.setText("CREATE PROPERTY E.out LINK");
OCommandSQL createIndexUniqueEdge= new OCommandSQL();
createIndexUniqueEdge.setText("CREATE INDEX unique_edge ON E (in, out) UNIQUE");
orientDBGraph.command(declareIn).execute();
orientDBGraph.command(declareOut).execute();               
orientDBGraph.command(createIndexUniqueEdge).execute();

System.out.println(createIndexUniqueEdge.getText());

String query10 = "select from index:unique_edge where key=#9:1";
Iterable<OrientVertex> res10 = orientDBGraph.command(new OCommandSQL(query10)).execute();

while(res10.iterator().hasNext()){
    OrientVertex source = res10.iterator().next();

    System.out.println(source.getId());


}
```

Comment: You should not create properties IN and OUT becuase is already present on class E.

Comment: Thanks, but I did it, without creating the in, out properties and I came out this error                                                                                                                 ............  Index with name 'unique_edge' cannot be created on class 'E' because the field 'in' is absent in class definition.........